# Query exceeding 16384 bytes, skipping. Probably a bulk insert query

Tags: mariadb

On MariaDB 5.5, Ubuntu 14.04

What actually happens when I restore a 170mb mysql dump file and info "Query exceeding 16384 bytes, skipping. Probably a bulk insert query." shows on cmon.log?

Does it mean that I would not have all my backup data restored?

Below is output of max_all settings

```
> show variables like '%max_all%';
+--------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name            | Value      |
+--------------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet       | 536870912  |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Probably your max packet size is set too low.

Comment: will this truncate dump restored?

Comment: Yes, the restore will have failed, at least partially.

Comment: by referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size this means that I need to set max_allowed_packet=500M if dump restored less than 500M?

Answer (score 1):

It has been confirmed by severalnines that the message is just cmon does not analyze those queries because of their sizes.

http://support.severalnines.com/entries/80914809-cmon-Query-exceeding-16384-bytes-skipping-Probably-a-bulk-insert-query-?page=1#post_29095145